# Reading data from USB mouse into microcontroller

Tags: interface, usb, mouse, microcontroller, psoc

As the title say, i have a USB mouse, which i wan't to connect to a microcontroller, more specific a PSoC 4. I want to be able to read its coordinates (x,y).

Is this possible to do, or is it simply to complicated?

best regards

Comment: Many microcontrollers have a USB host peripheral that would allow you to connect to devices such as a USB mouse.  You might consider getting an mbed board.  You would then have to find the right library to use on that board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [datasheet](http://www.cypress.com/file/46106/download):

> **5.7.12 Universal Serial Bus (USB)**
>
> PSoC 4 has a Full-speed USB 2.0 compliant device interface.

Since it has no host interface, only a device interface, you won't be able to connect a mouse via USB.